# SMTP GMAIL Connection

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I can't connect to SMTP GMAIL with PHPMailer.

here is error :

> Error on Jun 25, 2015 22:54PM - stream_socket_client(): unable to
>   connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection timed out) in
>   /home/amiroper/public_html/beporsbedoon/app/helpers/phpmailer/smtp.php
>   on line 222

and this is my code :

```
$this->_mail->isSMTP();
$this->_mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$this->_mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$this->_mail->Username = "amiroperator@gmail.com";
$this->_mail->Password = "*********";
$this->_mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$this->_mail->Port = "587";
$this->_mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$this->_mail->From = "AmirOperator";
$this->_mail->FromName = 'amiroperator@gmail.com';
$this->_mail->addAddress("amiroperator@outlook.com", "test");
$this->_mail->isHTML(true);
$this->_mail->Subject = 'Registration confirm';
$this->_mail->Body    = 'Thank you for registering to activate your account please click on this link. ".DIR."account/activate/$id/$activasion"';
$this->_mail->AltBody = 'Thank you for registering to activate your account please click on this link. ".DIR."account/activate/$id/$activasion"';

if(!$this->_mail->send()) {
    $data['mailsent'] = false;
} else {
    $data['mailsent'] = true;
}
```

the php code is wrong or this is connection problem

Comment: It's a connection problem  - your DNS isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server cannot connect to *smtp.gmail.com* on port *587*. I have the same problem from [a testing tool](https://www.wormly.com/test_smtp_server):

```
Resolving hostname...
Connecting...
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
Message sending failed.
```

From my local machine, it works perfectly:

```
Trying 74.125.195.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP be3sm8900765wib.21 - gsmtp
```

Maybe there are temporary problems at Google from the US (I am in Germany here) or something like this. There is no obvious mistake in your code. You can only try it again later or with another SMTP server.

Furthermore, you can try to connect with **74.125.195.108** directly (just deactivate SSL certificate validation).

---

EDIT: Just also try `tls://smtp.gmail.com` as host.

Comment: thanks, I'm from Iran. May in iran we have temporary problems with smtp.gmail.com, but with 74.125.195.108 I can connect.

Comment: That means you have a DNS problem.

Comment: @Synchro: I do not think so, because even the test page failed. Maybe this is a problem with SSL/TLS support of Google. The testing tool explicitly says, that *smtp.gmail.com* has been resolved.

Comment: @amiroperator: Just being careful with the fix IP address as it can be changed or being loadbalanced. Have you tried with the `tls://` prefix and hostname also?

Comment: You can use the prefix or the SMTPSecure property, it makes no difference which you use.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the authentication protocol and port number in your code:

```
// Your Current Settings
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

// Updated Settings
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Port = 465;
```

I've found that PHPMailer, when set to use Gmail SMTP servers with TLS authentication protocol and port number 587, simply doesn't work. However, I've never had a problem using SSL/465.

[Google SMTP Settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

[Difference Between TLS and SSL](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1074635?hl=en)