# PHPMailer error:

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i can't send email with PHPMailer. I have already read a lot of questions about this but none can help me

This is my config:

```
$this->IsSMTP();
$this->SMTPAuth = true;
$this->SMTPDebug = 2;
$this->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$this->Port = 587;
$this->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.googlemail.com'); //fix ipv6 problems
$this->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

And this is debug:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 smtp.googlemail.com ESMTP m62sm4902317qte.5 - gsmtp
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smtp.googlemail.com at your service, [189.61.226.25]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed: 
SMTP -> NOTICE:
EOF caught while checking if connected
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP GMAIL Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058038/smtp-gmail-connection)

Comment: It is not the same problem, i can connect, the problem is after the TLS protocol starts

Comment: Using an old, buggy version of PHPMailer. Update.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use this

```
    define('GUSER', 'yourt@gmail.com'); // GMail username
    define('GPWD', 'Password'); // GMail password
global $error;
    require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
//$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug =1;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 

$mail->Username = GUSER;  
$mail->Password = GPWD;           
$mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;


    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = $mail->Body;

$mail->AddAddress($to);
```

Comment: Unexplained code post based on obsolete example. Doesn't attempt to answer the question.